# How to replace entire date in a month with only the first date of the month? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data columns like this:

[image]

What I want to do is take the film_title, replace all the period_day with only the first date, take the plays_, and sum the plays.

How ever, i do not know how to replace all the other date with only the first date. What i tried is i i took the month of the date, and try to replace all the month with only the first date, here is the syntax:

```
select film_title, month(period_day) as period_month, plays_,sum(plays_) as accum_plays
from yaya_csv
group by period_month, film_title
order by film_title,period_month;
```

But, i don't know how to replace the month numbers with the first date that occurs.

I also tried to create a row number inside CTE to get the first date the occurs by the rownum "1", but it ends up too complicated.

What syntax i must do to replace all the date with the first date only? Thank You

Comment: *But, i don't know how to replace the month numbers with the first date that occurs.* Unclear. provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts and desired output for this data.

Comment: Yeah, it is not entirely clear what you want, but first date sounds like you may need min() function.

Comment: Can you provide more data examples, table description and your expected results? Do not post it like images but as text

Answer (score 0):

I already created a syntax like this

```
select 
       film_title, 
       concat(date_format(period_day,"%Y-%m"),'-01')
```